# Json.net deserialization is returning an empty object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using the code below for serialization.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { summary = summary });
```

`summary` is a custom object of type `SplunkDataModel`:

```
public class SplunkDataModel
{
    public SplunkDataModel() {}

    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int FailureCount { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, SplunkError> FailureEntity { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> JobInfo { get; set; }
    public string JobStatus { get; set; }
    public int SuccessCount { get; set; }
    public List<string> SuccessEntity { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}
```

Serialization results in the JSON below:

```
{
  "summary": {
    "Category": "category",
    "JobStatus": "Failure",
    "JobInfo": {
      "Course processing failed": "" 
    },
    "TotalCount": 0,
    "SuccessCount": 0,
    "FailureCount": 0,
    "FailureEntity": {},
    "SuccessEntity": []
  }
}
```

Now, for unit testing purposes, I need to deserialize it, but the code below is returning an object with empty values.  Where am I going wrong?

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SplunkDataModel>(contents);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you serialized your `SplunkDataModel` to JSON, you wrapped it in an object with a `summary` property.  Hence, when you deserialize the JSON back to objects, you need to use the same structure.  There are several ways to go about it; they all achieve the same result.

1. Declare a class to represent the root level of the JSON and deserialize into that:

   ```
   public class RootObject
   {
       public SplunkDataModel Summary { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(contents).Summary;
   ```
2. Or, deserialize by example to an instance of an anonymous type, then retrieve your object from the result:

   ```
   var anonExample = new { summary = new SplunkDataModel() };
   var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(contents, anonExample).summary;
   ```
3. Or, deserialize to a JObject, then materialize your object from that:

   ```
   JObject obj = JObject.Parse(contents);
   var deserialized = obj["summary"].ToObject<SplunkDataModel>();
   ```

Answer (score 42):

On my side, it was because I had no **public setter** for my properties.
Instead of having

```
public class MyClass
{        
    public int FileId { get; }
}
```

I should have

```
public class MyClass
{        
    public int FileId { get; set; }
}
```

silly mistake that cost me hours....

Comment: AKHHHH! OMG! Thanks!

Comment: right in my case there is internal public string Currency { get; internal set; }

Comment: @HamitYILDIRIM Aaargh... i pulled half my hair until i read your comment, thanks alot!

Comment: I dont know your code but there should be a problem interesting your code scope. Asynchronous function have to know that function call completed and ready to deserialize. For example you can use it in an arrow function @PhilNicholas

Comment: I faced the same problem as @HamitYILDIRIM DeserializeAsync would not map JSON properties with `{ get; internal set; }` I decorated the properties with the `[JsonInclude]` attribute and everything worked as expected.

Comment: If anyone is wondering, setting InternalsVisibleTo for the Newtonsoft.Json library doesnt fix this.